# Why is my Facebook access_token shorter than the example and missing the 'session part'?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm designing a Facebook app and trying to obtain the "location" of my friends.  Using the Graph API explorer tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ it's a snap.

However, when I make the call to get the access token, from a authenticated App user, the token I receive is shorter than the token generated from the Graph API explorer tool.  This shortened token allows me to receive basic friend information but **does not** allow me to retrieve the *location* object.  Doing some research seems to indicate that I am missing the 'session part' of the token http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

How am I able to retrieve this 'session part?'  Why is the token I receive from Facebook not the same token I receive from the Graph Explorer API?

Note: I made sure I'm requesting the necessary extended permissions to read my friends location.

Comment: Can you post an example of a token you get? Also, please elaborate on the process which resulting in this token.

Comment: try adding more info. Most likely, what you have is the app `access_token`. Try this [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Comment: @ifaour Ahh, yup.  That was it.  Thanks!

Comment: @frio80, cool. Added it as answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [user access token, wrong format](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7739662/user-access-token-wrong-format)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a **user** `access_token`. If you are using the PHP-SDK, then most likely you are using the **app** `access_token`.

The SDK will always get the app `access_token` and use it if no user `access_token` is present ([reference](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L336)):

```
/**
* Determines the access token that should be used for API calls.
* The first time this is called, $this->accessToken is set equal
* to either a valid user access token, or it's set to the application
* access token if a valid user access token wasn't available. Subsequent
* calls return whatever the first call returned.
*
* @return string The access token
*/
  public function getAccessToken() {
    if ($this->accessToken !== null) {
      // we've done this already and cached it. Just return.
      return $this->accessToken;
    }

    // first establish access token to be the application
    // access token, in case we navigate to the /oauth/access_token
    // endpoint, where SOME access token is required.
    $this->setAccessToken($this->getApplicationAccessToken());
    $user_access_token = $this->getUserAccessToken();
    if ($user_access_token) {
      $this->setAccessToken($user_access_token);
    }

    return $this->accessToken;
  }
```